# Grails - how to hide a date inside a form

Tags: forms, grails

I have an 'edit' view for a model that has several fields (one of which is a date). I only want a few of the fields visible to allow edits, so I just hide the other fields using `<g:hiddenField>`

But one of the fields is of type TimeStamp and I can't seem to find a way to hide this in the form. I tried

```
<g:form method="post" >
    <g:textField name="firstName" value="${applicationUserInstance?.firstName}" />
    <g:textField name="lastName" value="${applicationUserInstance?.lastName}" />
    <g:datePicker name="createDate" style="visibility:hidden;" precision="day" value="${applicationUserInstance.createDate}" />
```

The date picker is still visible. Any idea how to hide the date so that I can just pass this to the update method upon submit of the form. Many thanks.

Comment: If they screen's not going to change the value, why even have it in the form? The update action doesn't need to have all of the domain's properties in `params` to successfully bind to and update the instance.

Comment: +1 to Rob's comment.  It's dangerous to have those hidden fields in the form as a savvy user could easily tweak those values using firebug or something similar and post values that you don't want changed.  They shouldn't be in the form and the controller should actually be filtering them out of any parameter list that it's receiving.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just re-iterating Rob's comment here.  No need to put that on the form.  The only data you need on the form is the data you are updating and the ID of what is being updated.  Everything else will just stay the same...

```
def update = {
    def applicationUserInstance = User.get(param.id)
    // at this point applicationUserInstance.createDate is
    // correct.
    applicationUserInstance.properties = params
    // since no createDate was in the params, it doesn't change.
    // so you're good
    applicationUserInstance.save(flush:true)
}
```

Comment: Burt & Gregg thanks. I didn't know that .properties would keep the other values not passed with params. The example truly help with clarifying the answer.

Comment: I'm not sure it's ethical to get rep by repeating comments: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82099/answering-comment-answered-questions. I suggest that you mark the answer as community wiki.

Comment: @Victor - In this case, I don't mind. I thought about answering, but didn't, so it's my own fault for not taking the time. :)

Comment: I thought about that too.  Which is why I mentioned Rob in my answer.  I wasn't trying to be unethical.

Answer (score 1):

Actually my answer below might not be the right answer to your question. Otherwise if you really just have a createdDate-field, which should keep track, when the entry was created in the database, I suggest you do it the Grails-way and use the reserved keywords 'dateCreated' and 'lastUpdated'

Check [http://grails.org/doc/1.3.7/guide/5.%20Object%20Relational%20Mapping%20(GORM).html#5.5.1 Events and Auto Timestamping](http://grails.org/doc/1.3.7/guide/5.%20Object%20Relational%20Mapping%20%28GORM%29.html#5.5.1%20Events%20and%20Auto%20Timestamping)
on how to use these. If you use these then my answer below will be helpful to control the visibility of these fields 'dateCreated', 'lastUpdated'

### Suggestions for 'dateCreated', 'lastUpdated'

Probably you want this timestamp to be created automatically as you found it in the Grails documentation but you do not want it to be visible in your view.

Now, to exclude this timestamp from being visible, first 
`grails install-templates`

I assume you have grails-1.3.7

- Go to src/templates/scaffolding and check your gsp-files, e.g. 'create' and 'edit'
- Search for this line:

`<%  excludedProps = ["version", "id",`

and edit for example 'dateCreated'

`<%  excludedProps = ["dateCreated", "version", "id",`

There is also a tutorial on this topic http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-grails01209/index.html

Greetings,

Jan

Comment: Hey, great tip. Unfortunately, I can't change the model since it has 2 web services using the same model and would require too many changes. But this is quite useful for future projects.